# What's the difference between event-stream.through and event-stream.map

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, event-stream

According to the documentation in [event-stream](https://github.com/dominictarr/event-stream), seems like the difference of this two method is sync or async.
But I'm still not sure what the difference really means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the difference is basically something completely different:

While the `through` stream only re-emits, the `map` stream also is able to modify the data. The first one simply emits what it gets, the data is sent 1:1 to the subscriber. The last one has an additional transformation step, so the data may be 1:1, but does not need to be.

In other words, the `through` stream is a kind of *identity*, while the `map` is a kind of `mapping`.

Comment: But if I change the data in es.through with `that.emit('data', 'foo')` is then map and though the same?